Relation between stopping times and their filtrations
I have a question about the following problem (b). We say that for stopping times $ \sigma $ and $ \tau $, if $ \sigma \leq \tau $. This should mean that all elements in $\{\sigma \leq n\}$ are also in $\{\tau \leq n\}$, but not all elements in $\{\tau \leq n\}$ are in $\{\sigma \leq n\}$. Why then does the first step of the solution to part (b) state that $\{\tau \leq n\}$ is a subset of $\{\sigma \leq n\}$? Shouldn't it be the other way around?
PROBLEM:
Let $ \sigma $ and $ \tau $ be stopping times with respect to the filtration $ \left(\mathcal{F}_{n}\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $.
(a) Show that
$$
\mathcal{F}_{\tau} = \left\{A \in \mathcal{A} : A \cap \{\tau \leq n\} \in \mathcal{F}_{n} \text{ for all } n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}
$$
is a $ \sigma $-algebra.
(b) Show: If $ \sigma \leq \tau $, then $ \mathcal{F}_{\sigma} \subseteq \mathcal{F}_{\tau} $.
Solution:
(b) To prove: $ \sigma \leq \tau \Rightarrow \mathcal{F}_{\sigma} \subseteq \mathcal{F}_{\tau} $.
Let $ A \in \mathcal{F}_{\sigma} $. It holds that
$$
A \cap \underbrace{\{\tau \leq n\}}_{\subset \{\sigma \leq n\}} = \underbrace{A \cap \{\sigma \leq n\}}_{\in \mathcal{F}_{n} \text{, since } A \in \mathcal{F}_{\sigma}} \cap \underbrace{\{\tau \leq n\}}_{\in \mathcal{F}_{n}} \in \mathcal{F}_{n}.
$$
Thus, $ A \in \mathcal{F}_{\tau} $, and hence $ \mathcal{F}_{\sigma} \subseteq \mathcal{F}_{\tau} $.

We assume that $\sigma\leq \tau$. This implies that for every $\omega \in \Omega$ we have the pointwise relation $\sigma(\omega)\leq \tau(\omega)$. Now let $\omega \in \{\tau\leq n\}$. With the pointwise relation between $\sigma$ and $\tau$, we conclude that $\sigma(\omega)\leq \tau(\omega)\leq n$. Therefore, we also have $\omega \in \{\sigma \leq n\}$. But then - since $\omega \in \{\tau\leq n\}$ was arbitrary - it follows that $\{\tau \leq n\}\subseteq \{\sigma \leq n\}$ and so $\{\tau \leq n\}\cap \{\sigma \leq n\}=\{\tau \leq n\}$.

Perhaps I misunderstand the concept of stopping times. If an event $ A $ has occurred by time $ \sigma $, then it must automatically have occurred by or at time $ \tau $, because $ \sigma \leq \tau $, and thus $ A $ must also be in $ {\tau \leq n} $, or not? What is my error in thinking here?

@Hofnarr I have a feeling that the proper formalisation of your thought would be exactly point (b), that is $\mathscr{F}\sigma \subseteq \mathscr{F}\tau$. If that is the case, you are not committing any error with your intuition. However, from such intuition it does not follow that all elements of ${\sigma \leq n}$ are in ${\tau \leq n}$. There could be a case of an $\omega$ such that $\sigma(\omega)\leq n <\tau(\omega)$, so that $\omega \in {\sigma \leq n}$ but $\omega \notin {\tau\leq n}$.

ok I think I get it now thank you!

@Hofnarr please do upvote if you want to! :)

The notation $\sigma \leq \tau$ should be understood as an event that occurs with probability $1$, meaning $\{\omega \in \Omega : \sigma(\omega) \leq \tau(\omega)\} = \Omega$. If $\tau \leq n$, then it must be that $\sigma \leq n$, given that we have assumed $\sigma \leq \tau$. In terms of the sample space, this implies that any $\omega$ for which $\tau(\omega) \leq n$ will also satisfy $\sigma(\omega) \leq n$. In other words, $\{\tau \leq n\} \subseteq \{\sigma \leq n\}$ as events.

This answer is equivalent to mine, was posted much after, yet was upvoted unlike mine! Such silly mysteries on MathSE. I will upvote it too.

@Snoop I just wanted to highlight that $\sigma \leq \tau$ should be understood as an event (a certain one). Should've paid more attention to your answer though. In any case, I retributed the courtesy :)

@Snoop I thought marking your answer with the green checkmark was more valuable than an upvote xD
